# Can you implement 'sweep' using apply in R?

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I'm brushing up on my R skills and finally feel like I've mastered the [strange sweep function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444889/how-to-use-the-r-function-sweep) e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4)
sweep(df, MARGIN = 2, STATS = c(5, 10), FUN = "*")

##    a  b
## 1  5 20
## 2 10 30
## 3 15 40
```

and more usefully [here](http://rpubs.com/RobinLovelace/11685), on a tutorial I'm working on implementing a spatial interaction model in R.

They say that a sign you understand something is that you can say it in many ways, and I think this applies more in programming than almost anywhere else. Yet, despite the problem that `sweep` solves seeming `apply`-esque, I have NO IDEA whether they are to some degree interchangeable.

So, in order to improve my own understanding of R, is there any way to do the above procedure using `apply`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is close:

```
t(apply(df, 1, `*`, c(5,10)))
```

The row names are lost but otherwise the output is the same

```
> t(apply(df, 1, '*', c(5,10)))
      a  b
[1,]  5 20
[2,] 10 30
[3,] 15 40
```

To break this down, say we were doing this by hand for the first row of `df`, we'd write

```
> df[1, ] * c(5, 10)
  a  b
1 5 20
```

which is the same as calling the `'*'()` function with arguments `df[1, ]` and `c(5, 10)`

```
> '*'(df[1, ], c(5, 10))
  a  b
1 5 20
```

From this, we have enough to set up an `apply()` call:

1. we work by rows, hence `MARGIN = 1`,
2. we apply the function `'*'()` so `FUN = '*'`
3. we need to supply the second argument, `c(5,10)`,  to `'*'()`, which we do via the `...` argument of `apply()`.

The only extra thing to realise is how `apply()` sticks together the vector resulting from each "iteration"; here they are bound column-wise and hence we need to transpose the result from `apply()` so that we get the same output as `sweep()`.

Comment: Fantastic answer Gavin thank you. Only leaves the question: why is there a separate sweep function if you can do it all with apply?

Comment: @RobinLovelace Efficiency; try timing the two approaches. `sweep` applies `FUN` to all elements in one single call. `apply` sets up a `for` loop over the (in this case) rows and calls `FUN` `nrow` times. But `apply()` can do a lot more than `sweep()` can, so that generality comes with a price.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional information, since questions about `sweep` are recurring, quick benchmarking gives (on Intel i7-8700 with Windows)

```
x <- matrix(data = 20000*5000, nrow = 20000, ncol = 5000)
system.time(expr = {
  aa <- colMeans(x = x)
  bb <- sweep(x = x, MARGIN = 2, STATS = aa, FUN = "-")
})
#        user      system      elapsed
#        4.69        0.16        4.84 
system.time(expr = {
  bbb <- apply(X = x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(z) z - mean(x = z))
  bbb <- t(x = bbb)
})
#        user      system      elapsed
#        6.28        0.55        6.85
```

Meaning that `sweep` is more efficient when applicable.