# apply() vs. sweep() in R

Tags: r, row, apply

I was writing up notes to compare apply() and sweep() and discovered the following strange differences. In order the generate the same result, sweep() needs MARGIN = 1 while apply wants MARGIN = 2. Also the argument specifying the matrix is uppercase X in apply() but lowercase in sweep().

```
my.matrix <- matrix(seq(1,9,1), nrow=3)
row.sums <- rowSums(my.matrix)
apply.matrix <- apply(X = my.matrix, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function (x) x/row.sums)
sweep.matrix <- sweep(x = my.matrix, MARGIN = 1, STATS = rowSums(my.matrix), FUN="/")
apply.matrix - sweep.matrix ##yup same matrix
```

Isn't sweep() an "apply-type" function? Is this just another R quirk or have I lost my mind?

Comment: What is your question, i.e., what exactly is unclear after reading the documentation?

Comment: Question: do two closely related functions indeed have different syntax for the same problem?

Comment: Note that R has been developed over a long time and R-Core takes great care not to break existing code. Both of these functions are probably a legacy from S and compatibility with S/S-PLUS was a great concern in the early days.

Answer (score 5):

Note that for `apply`,

> If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’ returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’

In your example, `MARGIN` can (and should) be set to `1` in both cases; but the returned value from `apply` should be transposed.  This is easiest to see if the original matrix is not square:

```
my.matrix <- matrix(seq(1,12,1), nrow=4)
apply.matrix <- t(apply(X = my.matrix, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x)))
sweep.matrix <- sweep(x = my.matrix, MARGIN = 1, STATS = rowSums(my.matrix), FUN="/")
all.equal(apply.matrix, sweep.matrix)
# [1] TRUE
```

Also see this answer to [Can you implement 'sweep' using apply in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875426/can-you-implement-sweep-using-apply-in-r/20875506#20875506), which says very much the same thing.