# Using "apply" to apply a function to a matrix where parameters are column-specific

Tags: r, apply

I'm trying to avoid using loops by using `apply` to apply a user-defined function to a matrix. The problem I have is that there are additional parameters that my function uses and they differ for each column of the matrix. Below is a toy example.

Say I have the following function:

```
foo <- function(x, a, b, c) return( (a*x + b)^c )
```

and I want to apply it to a matrix `bar` using different values of `a`, `b`, and `c` for each column.

```
bar <- matrix(1:15, ncol = 3)
a <- 4:6
b <- 3:1
c <- 1:3
```

In this case, for the first column of `bar`, then `a=4`, `b=3`, and `c=1`. I tried this,

```
apply(bar, 2, foo, a=a, b=b, c=c)
```

but this is clearly incorrect, as each column uses all parameters sequentially before wrapping back to the first parameter again. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We could `split` the 'bar' by 'column' (`col(bar)`) and with `mapply` we can apply 'foo' for the corresponding 'a', 'b', 'c' values to each column of 'bar'

```
mapply(foo, split(bar, col(bar)), a, b, c)
```

Or without using `apply`

```
ind <- col(bar)
(a[ind]*bar +b[ind])^c[ind]
```

Comment: Instead of `split` you can use also `as.data.frame`.

Comment: @nicola Yes, I thought to keep it in the `matrix`

Comment: I'd already upvoted the first one and now wish there were the ability to add votes for exceptionally elegant edits.

Answer (score 9):

I don't see why you bother with a function at all:

```
> a <- matrix(4:6,nrow = 5,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)
> b <- matrix(3:1,nrow = 5,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)
> c <- matrix(1:3,nrow = 5,ncol = 3,byrow = TRUE)
> (a*bar + b)^c
     [,1] [,2]   [,3]
[1,]    7 1024 300763
[2,]   11 1369 389017
[3,]   15 1764 493039
[4,]   19 2209 614125
[5,]   23 2704 753571
```

Comment: @akrun Ah, I missed the end of your answer.

Comment: It's okay.  I wouldn't have guessed it anyway

Comment: @akrun I actually think your use of `col` is much better.

Comment: I think `rep` might be a bit more faster compared to recycling and `col`

Comment: @joran The code I give above is just a toy example. The real problem uses a much more complex function that was defined by someone else in an R package – specifically `tran.1D` in the `ReacTran` package.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you can just transpose your matrix and use vectorization:

```
t(foo(t(bar),a,b,c))
```

This should work for every vectorized `foo`.

Answer (score 2):

You could put your parameters into the vector:

```
newbar <- rbind(a,b,c,bar)
newfoo <- function(z){x <- z[-(1:3)]; (z[1]*x+z[2])^z[3]}
apply(newbar,2,newfoo)
```

which gives

```
[,1] [,2]   [,3]
    7 1024 300763
   11 1369 389017
   15 1764 493039
   19 2209 614125
   23 2704 753571
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sweep`; usually this is for subtracting the mean from each column, but you can pass in an index instead to get parallel indexing across a,b and c:

```
> sweep(bar, 2, seq_along(a), function(x,i) foo(x, a[i], b[i], c[i]), FALSE)
     [,1] [,2]   [,3]
[1,]    7 1024 300763
[2,]   11 1369 389017
[3,]   15 1764 493039
[4,]   19 2209 614125
[5,]   23 2704 753571
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444889/how-to-use-the-r-function-sweep