# "Could someone please define "sweep" without using the word "sweep" in the definition?

Tags: r

The problem is that function definitions, such as that of "sweep" are often explained in a way that offers little further information.  "Sweep" "sweeps out" things.  I don't know what that means, and have little chance of finding out what it means by reading the definition.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the 'sweep' function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444889/how-to-use-the-sweep-function)

Comment: @kslew, That question is how it is used but this question is what does it do.

Answer (score 3):

The `sweep()` function iterates through a matrix by row (`MARGIN = 1`) or column (`MARGIN = 2`) and performs some operation that you want (defined by `FUN`) taking the input of (`STATS`). As such, it is useful for performing some operation (`FUN`) across rows/columns with different inputs.

Using d.b.'s example in the comments, suppose you have a 3x3 matrix full of 0s:

```r
m <- matrix(0, 3, 3)
m

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

If you want to add 7 to the first column, 3 to the second column, and 11 to the third column (passed to `STATS`):

```r
sweep(x = m, MARGIN = 2, STATS = c(7, 3, 11), FUN = "+")

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    3   11
[2,]    7    3   11
[3,]    7    3   11
```

or you can do it by row (`MARGIN = 1`):

```r
sweep(x = m, MARGIN = 1, STATS = c(7, 3, 11), FUN = "+")

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    7    7    7
[2,]    3    3    3
[3,]   11   11   11
```

Thus, the `sweep()` function is most useful when you want to apply a different value to a given function across rows/columns of your matrix. (Note: You can also apply the function across cells with `MARGIN = 1:2`).

Answer (score 0):

If the operation given in the 4th argument is minus then sweep refers to subtracting the third argument from each row or column of the first argument.

A special case may make it clearer.  We will use the built-in 6x2 `BOD` data frame and use subtraction for the 4th argument.

Then `sweep(BOD, 1, v, "-")` subtracts the vector `v` from each column of `BOD` giving an identical result to `BOD - cbind(v, v)` (which can be simplified to just `BOD - v`).   Similarly `sweep(BOD, 2, u, "-")` subtracts the vector `u` from each row of `BOD` giving an identical result as `BOD - rbind(u, u, u, u, u, u)` .

In detail, we provide several equivalences for each of the two cases.

```
# MARGIN = 1 case.  These each give identical reesults.

v <- rowMeans(BOD) # any vector having length of nrows(BOD) would work
sweep(BOD, 1, v, "-")

BOD - cbind(v, v)

BOD - matrix(v, nrow(BOD), ncol(BOD))

cbind(BOD[1] - v, BOD[2] - v)

BOD - v
```

In words for the MARGIN=2 case it subtracts the vector u from each row.  These each give identical results except as noted.

```
# MARGIN = 2 case.  These each give identical results except as noted.

u <- colMeans(BOD) # any vector of length ncol(BOD) will work
sweep(BOD, 2, u, "-")

BOD - rbind(u, u, u, u, u, u)

BOD - matrix(u, nrow(BOD), ncol(BOD), byrow = TRUE)

rbind(BOD[1, ] - u, BOD[2, ] - u, BOD[3, ] - u, BOD[4, ] - u, 
  BOD[5, ] - u, BOD[6, ] - u)

mapply("-", BOD, u)  # matrix rather than data.frame

scale(BOD, scale = FALSE)  # matrix rather than data.frame
```